# SAPUI5 url white list concept

Tags: security, web, sapui5, whitelist

I do not understand the concept of the url white list restriction. This documentation [API](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_scm700_ehp03/helpdata/en/91/f3768f6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/content.htm) says that every url which is not listed in this list is not allowed. In the application I have to add urls to the whitlist object with "jQuery.sap.addUrlWhitelist", but everybody can add also malicious urls by runtime. So what is the benefit of this concept?

Comment: Well.. consider it as a flaw, but that's how it is. You can modify anything at anytime if it's displayed in a browser. Enable disabled stuff, show hidden stuff, modify stuff... that's how the **dev tools** work. But the average internet user doesn't even know about F12 ;)

Comment: Hi Marc thanks for your reply. But this is a security concept from SAP. There has to be more than my first thought about this security pattern...

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation:

```
To allow that the OpenUI5 application is embedded in cross-origin domains, configure a whitelist service. The whitelist service checks whether the application can run in the parent origin, or not.
```

Its the only thing i found where the whitelist is mentioned as a reasonable example. For Example you can display in embedded Applications a custom "not allowed message/view". So the benefit is you can react to not allowed embedding in a proper way

But as already mentioned in the comments its a client side mechanism, which is ALWAYS unsafe as it is executed in the Browser. But it may save in some cases a roundtrip to the server

Here the link for the documentation: https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/62d9c4d8f5ad49aa914624af9551beb7.html